# Missing 900GB of space on a 1TB hard drive

Tags: linux-mint, disk-usage

I am using Linux Mint 20.3. I have a 1TB HDD and my root directory takes up 42GB. How is it that I only have 100GB left of free space, where did it go? What could explain such a big loss in storage?

I did run `fdisk` several times to fix bad sectors preventing me from booting up. Could almost all my hard drive be unusasable?

[image: Baobab output ran with sudo]

`df -hPT` outputs this:

```
>Filesystem               Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                     devtmpfs  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    tmpfs     779M  1.7M  777M   1% /run
/dev/sda2                ext4      916G  666G  204G  77% /
tmpfs                    tmpfs     3.8G   30M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                    tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                vfat      511M  5.4M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                    tmpfs     779M   24K  779M   1% /run/user/1000
/home/bernetues/.Private ecryptfs  916G  666G  204G  77% /home/bernetues
/dev/sdb1                iso9660   409M  409M     0 100% /media/bernetues/CDROM
```

`sudo du -h / 2> /dev/null | sort -hr | head` outputs this:

[image: sudo du -h / 2> /dev/null | sort -hr | head output]

Comment: check your disk with `testdisk`

Comment: Might you share the output of `df -hPT` with us?  Also, might you share the output of `sudo du -h / 2> /dev/null | sort -hr | head`?

Comment: The command took a long time to execute. I updated the main question

Comment: You have 666G in your home dir encrypted with is that why it is not showing?

Comment: Grasping at straws here; though, perhaps you have open handles referencing removed/non-existent files associated with considerable space!?  Did you recently delete any large files that may still have handles open with still running processes?  Might something have autonomously created large files and deleted them?  Perhaps check `lsof | grep '/home/bernetues'` and the like!?

Comment: Perhaps consider running something along the lines of: `lsof | grep ' (deleted)$'` or, if your `lsof` doesn't report deletions, then something along the lines of: `while read f; do [[ -e $f ]] && continue; echo $f; done <<< $( lsof | grep '\bREG\b' | sed -re 's/(\S+\s+){4}REG\s+(\S+\s+){3}(.+)/\3/' )`.

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: @djmonki  Please make that comment an answer. Interesting that an ecryptfs wrapped in a user directory does not get counted in the GUI-style report.

Answer (score 2):

You have 666G in your home dir encrypted with ecryptfs, is that why it is not showing?

Looks like ecryptfs wrapped in a user directory does not get counted in the GUI-style report, but does show for `df -hPT` output.

Answer (score 0):

`du` and equivalent tools can only report on files that they can see. If permissions are set to make a directory unreadable then they are not included. It will also not find files that are still open (by a process), but removed from all directories.

`df` only looks at device size, and free blocks. It does not need any special permissions.

If `du` is reading low for used space, then it is because it did not find it.